# Show 2 rows for single record in DataGid

Tags: asp.net, datagrid

I have following Fiedls in DataGrid

```
4 Bound Filed,
1 Dropdown,
3 Button
```

Now I want to display Bound fields in one row and dropdown and buttons in second row.
Because of some reasons i can use only Datagrid. i can`t use any other contols.

So how can I show data in two rows?

My code is as below:

```
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Market"> </asp:BoundColumn> 
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="DrawPrice" H> </asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name2"> </asp:BoundColumn> 
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="AwayPrice"> </asp:BoundColumn> 
<asp:TemplateColumn> 
    <ItemTemplate> 
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btn1" runat="server" CommandName="btn1"/> 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btn2" runat="server" CommandName="btn2"/> 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btn3" runat="server" CommandName="btn3"/> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateColumn>
```

Comment: Are you actually using ye old `DataGrid`, or are you using a `GridView`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one cell in the DataGrid as a container for a HTML table with 2 rows and 2 columns, the second row spanning two columns.

You can achieve this by using a TemplateColumn, in which you put the HTML for the table. Also add the `<%# %>` binding blocks for the 3 data fields (in the same `TemplateColumn`).

Comment: Hello, I don`t want to change in bound field. I can`t use <%# %> in place of bound field. I can use only bound field. So is that any other idea?

Comment: <asp:BoundColumn DataField="Market">
</asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="DrawPrice" H>
</asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="Name2">
</asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:BoundColumn DataField="AwayPrice">
</asp:BoundColumn>
<asp:TemplateColumn>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn1" runat="server" CommandName="btn1"/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn2" runat="server" CommandName="btn2"/>
<asp:LinkButton ID="btn3" runat="server" CommandName="btn3"/>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateColumn>